# Обновление ПО Debian 3 php 5.6 bitrix

Tags: php, linux, битрикс, debian

имеется сервер на Debian 3, на нем же крутиться bitrix с версией php 5.6.

Как обновить версию ПО и не положить сайт?

Comment: А обновить-то что надо? php? bitrix? debian?

Comment: Обновить debian не трогая работоспособность сайта

Comment: с учетом что стабильный дебиан сейчас в версии 11, то проще поставить новый сервер и на него сайт перенести.

Comment: да и php5.6 сейчас только из исходников собирать походу.

Comment: Ну а можно перенести на debian 11 сайт на php 5.6?Это возможно если да то можно совет? Если нет то как быть?

Comment: В битриксе есть инструменты для бэкапа. Бекапишь БД, всю папку с сайтом и несешь все это на новый сервер.

Comment: Сначала потренироваться в виртуальной машине, отловить все возможные проблемы и найти для них решения, а уже потом набраться смелости и отправиться устанавливать настоящий сервер

Comment: ещё надо учесть версию битрикса, т.к. старый битрикс на новом php не заработает скорее всего. Т.е. php обновить до последнего не получится, а до определённой версии, если битрикс не обновлять. В идеале потренироваться, хоть локально, потом выбрать незагруженное время, например ночь, затем закрыть публичную часть сайта , есть кнопка в главном модуле, сделать всё и открыть публичку.

Comment: Всем спасибо задача решена!